# In AngularJS, why can $emit events can be canceled but not $broadcast events?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Is it because of the one-to-many relationship of parent-to-child scopes?

Comment: Interesting question. Even with one to many relation we should be able to stop it.

Comment: @JoelKornbluh That is not what documentation says: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$broadcast

It is not a JS event, it is an angular event.

Comment: @Arashsoft you're right. I missed that.

Answer (score 2):

[`$emit`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$emit) "Dispatches an event name ***upwards*** through the scope hierarchy", while [`$broadcast`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$broadcast) "Dispatches an event name ***downwards*** to all child scopes (and their children)"

Looking at the [source code](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.7/angular.js) we can see that `$emit` has both `event.stopPropagation()` and `event.preventDefault()`

```
$emit: function(name, args) {
    var empty = [],
        namedListeners,
        scope = this,
        stopPropagation = false,
        event = {
          name: name,
          targetScope: scope,
          stopPropagation: function() {stopPropagation = true;},
          preventDefault: function() {
            event.defaultPrevented = true;
          },
          defaultPrevented: false
        },
// ...
```

while `$broadcast` only has `event.preventDefault()`

```
$broadcast: function(name, args) {
    var target = this,
        current = target,
        next = target,
        event = {
          name: name,
          targetScope: target,
          preventDefault: function() {
            event.defaultPrevented = true;
          },
          defaultPrevented: false
        };
// ...
```

This leads me to believe that the mechnism simply relies on [DOM bubbling](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-flow): events travel *up* and can be prevented from propagating upward (with `event.stopPropagation()`), but the is no mechanism to prevent propagating downward.

Answer (score 1):

The only difference between the $brodcast and $emit is the $emit always looks for the bottom to the top hierarchy to find it's parent and logically there will be only one parent scope. Hence it can call stopPropagation anytime to cancel further propagation of the event.

Whereas the $brodcast works top to bottom and there will be chances for many siblings controllers listening for the event. 
For Example $rootscope.$brodcast may be listened by many sibling controllers and it is not possible to stopPropagation.

Ultimately the answer to your question is yes, presumably stopPropagation is not implemented for $brodcast because of one-to-many(siblings) issue.
Check out this [link](http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/5d8be0b6-e294-457e-82b0-ba7cc10cae0e.aspx) for more understanding.